# Change of bases for entropy

Tags: information-theory, entropy

From Cover and Thomas, Elements of Information Theory:

[image]

Why isn't it: $ \log_b(p) = \frac{\log_a(p)}{\log_a(b)} $, so that $ H_a(X) $ is multiplied with $ \frac{1}{\log_b a} $?

Comment: $$\log_{b}a = \frac{1}{\log_{a}b}.$$

Comment: Are you clear on why $$\log_{b}a = \frac{1}{\log_{a}b}?$$ (=